# How to add TTL to Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Do anyone know how to add TTL to Azure DocumentDB ? I tried putting a property called "TTL" with value 1 to delete after 1 sec (for testing). But its not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first need to enable ttl for your collection. This is found in the Settings blade in the portal:

[image: ttl setting]

You'll want to turn this on. Then you can work with the `ttl` property for new documents (or with older documents which have a `ttl` property already).

Also note: The property name should be `ttl`, not `TTL`.

Answer (score 2):

David's answer is great and I don't want to repeat the same, just wanted to add few more points.

Either you can set the TTL from portal under setting like David said else you can control programmatically. TTL can be set for all document under collection level or for certain type of document (if you want to auto delete a particular type of document after some interval)

Also you can reset the TTL on a already existing document by doing any write operation on the document. Doing this will set the _ts to the current time, and the countdown to the document expiry, as set by the ttl, will begin again. If you wish to change the ttl of a document, you can update the field as you can do with any other settable field.

```
collection.setDefaultTimeToLive(259200) //collection level
document.setTimeToLive(259200) //document level
```

More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live)

```
//This is how the driver handles internally
public void setTimeToLive(Integer timeToLive)
{
    if (timeToLive != null) {
        super.set("ttl", timeToLive);
    } else if (super.has("ttl")) {
        super.remove("ttl");
    }
}
```